# Why doesn't scrollView work with textView? I'm trying it on Android 2.2 emulator

Tags: android, scrollview

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

       <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="EN LEZİZ KISIR TARİFİ BURADA"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/kisir" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/malzemeler" />

     <Button
       android:id="@+id/button2"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/hazirlanisi" />


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

         <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="@string/secenek" />

     </ScrollView>

  </LinearLayout>
```

When i click the button i want to be able to use the scrollView to be able to read the rest of the text and i kept text long in string values but i couldn't create scrollView. Where am i doing wrong? Thx.

Comment: is textview at bottom of screen or any space available at bottom of screen ?

Comment: If the text is more, which is not able to fit in available screen area then scroller will appear to scroll. Its working for me. Can you able to see at least partial text or full text you given ?

Comment: i was able to see the partial of text and if i use the down arrow on my keyboard i could see the rest of it but i couldn't work scrollView before i change as Yuvi said. Now it forces to close in emulator.

Comment: i am using android 2.2 device, its working here. i don't know why you are getting force close :-(

Comment: Apperantly scrollView was working from the beginning but because it wasn't stable,i couldn't get it. I see it now,it is a little bit hard to use but that's ok.=) Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `scrollview` inside the `textview`. You can use the scrollview instead of Linear layout. You are using scrollview in the wrong place.

Comment: problem is not emulator.you cannot use the scrollview inside the   layout

Comment: No, i can use Scrollview inside layout. Try the layout above. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Your Text" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I made as you said:  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
                                                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                              android:scrollbars="vertical" 
                                                            android:lines="15"
                                            android:text="@string/secenek"
           />                                                                                                               i also moved the scrollview but it forces to close in emulator.

Comment: I have updated my answer to make thing easier for you. Insert this where ever you want text to be scrollable.